# Trying to run a service in the background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I've just started learning how to create simple android apps via some code examples.

I took an audio capture code example that had only used an Activity and wanted to add a Service to it. So that the user will click a button from the view and then the activity will start/stop the audio recording service.

The goal is that the user will enter the app, click the 'start' button and then the service will start and will remain in the background forever until he returns to the app and clicks 'stop'.

Problem is, whenever I leave the app and open the 'recent apps' and slide out my app, I can see the `Congrats! MyService Created` and the `My Service Started` messages for some reason. I'm not sure why the service is being restarted when I slide it out of the recent apps menu, I would expect it to either continue running or close..

**record.java (activity):**

```
package com.example.recordtocloud;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class record extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    private Button start,stop,play;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        //stop.setEnabled(false);
        //play.setEnabled(false);

    }

    public void start(View view){
        startService(new Intent(this, recordbg.class));

        //start.setEnabled(false);
        //stop.setEnabled(true);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void stop(View view){
        stopService(new Intent(this, recordbg.class));

        //stop.setEnabled(false);
        //play.setEnabled(true);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",
                //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void play(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{

        MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
        m.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.3gp");
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**recordbg.java (service):**

```
package com.example.recordtocloud;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

public class recordbg extends Service {
    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile = null;
    private static final String TAG = "recordbg";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.3gp";

        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        try {
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        myAudioRecorder.stop();
        myAudioRecorder.release();
        myAudioRecorder  = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A "forever" background service don't exist in Android for two reasons:

1. Without a wakelock the cpu can go to deep sleep;
2. OS can kill your process at any time.

For the point 1) you can grab a wakelock to keep the cpu awake. For the point 2) you could create a foreground service. A foreground service can be killed by the OS but with a very low probability.

**Edit:**
Update your code because you have to implement onStartCommand() instead of onStart(), See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Can you tell me if the service I have listed above is currently 'foreground'? Also, why I'm I seeing the 'service created' and 'service started' messages when I remove the app from the 'recent apps' menu?

Comment: No your service is not in foreground. Maybe the OS is killing and restarting your app. In addition you have to implement onStartCommand(), see my update.